How to recognize recurring patterns in string ? For music chords chorus/verse automatic recognition
I work in JS and am seeking for a way of recognizing repeating patterns in chords from songs.
Here is the input (hotel california chords):
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 F C E7 Am F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 F C E7 Am F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 Am E7 

And here is the results I'm looking for:
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
F C E7 Am F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
F C E7 Am F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7
Am E7 G D F C Dm E7

As you can see, 2 long patterns have been found: Am E7 G D F C Dm E7 and F C E7 Am F C Dm E7 so the string was split accordingly. The rest of the non-patterns remains as it is and the minimum pattern length should be 3 to avoid too short patterns.
Of course, patterns are not given but should be idendtified on their own by the algorithm.
Any simple (or less simple) ways to do that?

I think it is simpler if you split the input string into an array and work with nested loops.

Simple approach: start by grouping into chunks of 3 or 4 notes, which I guess is common to all songs you want to recognise. (If not, do a loop over all possible sizes). If the number of distinct chunks is significantly (for some arbitrary significance factor…) less than the number of all chunks, you found a match. You can then repeat the approach on those patterns (e.g. by chunking the array of 4-note-patterns into long-patterns of size 2, or 3, or 6) to find the long patterns
